# Disable native events on chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, automation, driver

Hi I want to disable native events from Chrome driver, I did not find the way to do it, I just found examples for Firefox:

```
dcBrowser = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
FirefoxProfile prof2 = new FirefoxProfile(); 
prof2.setEnableNativeEvents(false); 
dcBrowser.setCapability("firefox_profile", prof2);
```

I tried to do the same for Chrome

```
dcBrowser = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeProfile prof2 = new ChromeProfile(); 
prof2.setEnableNativeEvents(false); 
dcBrowser.setCapability("chrome_profile", prof2);
```

When I add the import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeProfile;
```

I get the following error:

> The import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeProfile cannot be resolved

I know the ChromeProfile class does exists, but since I didn't find any example of disabling chrome native events I don't know if what I did is correct or not or maybe I am missing something, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent. Chrome always has native events enabled.

See: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions#native-events-versus-synthetic-events

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java, you can simply use 
`super.setNativeEvents(false);`